# Join 2 tables with different number of rows

Tags: mysql, join

I would like to join 2 tables (contact and contact_meta) in ONE sql query knowing that `contact_meta` has several rows

Contact

```
id    fname    lname      email
1     Nick     John       njohn@gmail.com
2     Laura    Pitt       lpitt@gmail.com
```

Contact_meta

```
id_contact      contact_meta_key      contact_meta_value
1               Newsletter            yes
1               Level                 weak
2               Newsletter            yes
```

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM contact as c 
JOIN contact_meta as cm  ON c.id = cm.id_contact
```

but where there are more than one row in contact_meta, I only get the last one.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [lname] => Nick [fname] => John [email] => njohn@gmail.com [contact_meta_key] => level [contact_meta_value] => weak ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [lname] => Laura [fname] => pitt [email] => lpitt@gmail.com [contact_meta_key] => newsletter [contact_meta_value] => yes 
);
```

Moreover, I would like `[newsletter] => yes instead of [contact_meta_key] => newsletter [contact_meta_value] => yes`

What I wish :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [lname] => Nick [fname] => John [email] => njohn@gmail.com [level] => weak [newsletter] => yes) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [lname] => Laura [fname] => pitt [email] => lpitt@gmail.com [newsletter] => yes
);
```

Comment: You shouldn't get either of those results from that query. You should get 3 rows of results: 2 rows for Nick, 1 row for Laura.

Comment: How do you define the *last* one?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rQpeqK4JmvVda46QC6CHjc/0

Comment: If you want to get `level` and `newsletter` columns in the result, you need to pivot the table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pivot the meta table.

```
SELECT c.*,
    MAX(IF(contact_meta_key = 'Newsletter', contact_meta_value, NULL)) AS newsletter,
    MAX(IF(contact_meta_key = 'Level', contact_meta_value, NULL)) AS level
FROM contact AS c
LEFT JOIN contact_meta AS cm ON c.id = cm.id_contact
GROUP BY c.id
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rQpeqK4JmvVda46QC6CHjc/1)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is today John has 2 entries in contact_meta but tomorrow it can be 5 and Laura 9, I store many datas in it. If it possible to get all meta datas contact from users in 1 SQL query.

I found a solution but I think not good, because 2 SQL queries (I use Wordpress) :

$user = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM contact as c JOIN relation_browser_contact as rbc  ON c.contact_id = rbc.id_contact JOIN browser as b ON rbc.id_browser = b.browser_id");

```
            $fellows = array();
            $i=0;
            foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
                $data=array();
                foreach ($user[$i] as $key => $value) {
                    if ( Helper::encrypt_decrypt('decrypt', $value) ){
                        $data[$key] = Helper::encrypt_decrypt('decrypt', $value);
                    }else{
                        $data[$key] = $value;
                    }

                    $metas = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT contact_meta_key, contact_meta_value FROM contact_meta WHERE id_contact = ".$user[$i]->contact_id );

                    foreach ($metas as $key => $value) {
                        $data[$value->contact_meta_key] = $value->contact_meta_value;
                    }

                }
                $fellows[] = $data;
                $i++;
            }

    print_r($fellows);
```

In this case, I have all I want, but just wondering if SQL query can do it...